# Define a custom sortperm function

Tags: sorting, matrix, mapping, julia

In Julia, let's suppose I have the following matrix:

```
julia> rank = [[1.0,2.0,NaN] [5.0,3.0,1.0]]
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
   1.0  5.0
   2.0  3.0
 NaN    1.0
```

Using `mapslices` and `sortperm` to get a ranking on each column gives:

```
 r = mapslices(sortperm, rank; dims=1)
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3
 2  2
 3  1
```

The problem being that `NaN` are considered as "worst" elements instead of being kept in final matrix. What I finally want is:

```
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3
 2  2
 NaN  1
```

My current workaround is to compare each element of `r` with those of `rank`. But I'm quite sure Julia has a classier way of doing it :p.

Current workaround: not enough because requires extra computation after `mapslices` as well as creating another array `new_r`.

```
nrow, ncol = size(r)
new_r = [Float64(ifelse(isnan(rank[i,j]), NaN, r[i,j])) for i in 1:nrow, j in 1:ncol]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` is not "special" in Julia. It is just a floating point value. If you want `NaN` to be treated as missing value you should first convert it to `missing` and then use `ordinalrank` function from StatsBase.jl:

```
julia> rank = [[1.0,2.0,NaN] [5.0,3.0,1.0]]
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
   1.0  5.0
   2.0  3.0
 NaN    1.0

julia> using StatsBase

julia> mapslices(rank; dims=1) do x
           ordinalrank(replace(x, NaN=>missing))
       end
3×2 Array{Union{Missing, Int64},2}:
 1         3
 2         2
  missing  1
```